# My screen behaves strangely on Debian

Tags: debian, intel, bumblebee, optimus

Video

https://streamable.com/95f2v

Hi.

I'm running Debian since last week. I don't know why but my screen behaves strangely and I can't find a reason.. Only reboot helps. Have any ideas?

Info:

```
lspci -nn | grep -i 'vga\|3d'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616] (rev 09)
04:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] [10de:1299] (rev a1)

$ cat /etc/debian_version 
9.3

$ uname -r
4.9.0-5-amd64


$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:

$ optirun glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 920M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.82
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.82
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:

$ dpkg -l | grep -e linux-image -e linux-headers -e xorg -e mesa -e firmware
ii  firmware-linux-free                  3.4                               all          Binary firmware for various drivers in the Linux kernel
ii  firmware-realtek                     20161130-3                        all          Binary firmware for Realtek wired/wifi/BT adapters
ii  glx-alternative-mesa                 0.7.4                             amd64        allows the selection of MESA as GLX provider
ii  libegl1-mesa:amd64                   13.0.6-1+b2                       amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- runtime
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64                13.0.6-1+b2                       amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64                13.0.6-1+b2                       amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libglapi-mesa:amd64                  13.0.6-1+b2                       amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglu1-mesa:amd64                   9.0.0-2.1                         amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64           13.0.6-1+b2                       amd64        implementation of the Wayland EGL platform -- runtime
ii  linux-headers-4.9.0-5-amd64          4.9.65-3+deb9u2                   amd64        Header files for Linux 4.9.0-5-amd64
ii  linux-headers-4.9.0-5-common         4.9.65-3+deb9u2                   all          Common header files for Linux 4.9.0-5
ii  linux-headers-amd64                  4.9+80+deb9u3                     amd64        Header files for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
ii  linux-image-4.9.0-4-amd64            4.9.65-3+deb9u1                   amd64        Linux 4.9 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-4.9.0-5-amd64            4.9.65-3+deb9u2                   amd64        Linux 4.9 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-amd64                    4.9+80+deb9u3                     amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
ii  mesa-utils                           8.3.0-3                           amd64        Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities
ii  mesa-va-drivers:amd64                13.0.6-1+b2                       amd64        Mesa VA-API video acceleration drivers
ii  mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64             13.0.6-1+b2                       amd64        Mesa VDPAU video acceleration drivers
ii  xorg                                 1:7.7+19                          amd64        X.Org X Window System
ii  xorg-docs-core                       1:1.7.1-1                         all          Core documentation for the X.org X Window System
ii  xserver-xorg                         1:7.7+19                          amd64        X.Org X server
ii  xserver-xorg-core                    2:1.19.2-1+deb9u2                 amd64        Xorg X server - core server
ii  xserver-xorg-input-all               1:7.7+19                          amd64        X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-input-libinput          0.23.0-2                          amd64        X.Org X server -- libinput input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-wacom             0.34.0-1                          amd64        X.Org X server -- Wacom input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-legacy                  2:1.19.2-1+deb9u2                 amd64        setuid root Xorg server wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-all               1:7.7+19                          amd64        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu            1.2.0-1+b1                        amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati               1:7.8.0-1+b1                      amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev             1:0.4.4-1+b5                      amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel             2:2.99.917+git20161206-1          amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau           1:1.0.13-3                        amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia            375.82-1~deb9u1                   amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl               0.1.4+20161126git4d7160c-1        amd64        X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon            1:7.8.0-1+b1                      amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa              1:2.3.4-1+b2                      amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware            1:13.2.1-1+b1                     amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver
```

Comment: Does that happen with other screens too? Or, using the same screen, does the same happen with different computers/gfx_cards?

Comment: I don't know. This is a notebook. I can't check it. But when i had Windows something like that didn't happen.

Comment: Try USB  live-booting another distro, older kernel, or newer kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade to 4.9.0-3 solves the problem.